# When using scale_fill_manual() in a loop, only the colour values assigned in the last iteration are retained

Tags: r, ggplot2

Explanation of code: I have a data frame `dfs` in which I store the names of other data frames (`df1` and `df2`). Both `df1` and `df2` contain data on two distributions.

I want to make two separate (double) bar graphs; one for `df1` and `df2`. Each bar graph compares two distributions. The colours of the bars to be used are listed in `dfs` (e.g. for `df1` I want to use `red1` and `red4`).

I tried doing this by looping through the data frame `dfs` (this is just an illustrative example, in reality I have much more data frames than only `df1` and `df2`) and creating a bar graph object for each data frame 'df1' and 'df2'.

I use `scale_fill_manual(values = barColours)` to assign the colours to the bars. Unfortunately, when I plot the figures in the end (`df1_plot` and `df2_plot`), the colours of the last iteration are used (in other words, the colours for `df2_plot` are also used for `df1_plot`).

**Is there a way to ensure that `df1_plot` uses the intended colours without losing the `for` loop?**

```
library(ggplot2)
col1          = c("red1", "green1")
col2          = c("red4", "green4")
dfs           = data.frame(df = c("df1", "df2"), col1, col2 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

category_type1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)
category1      = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 2)
weight1        = c(5, 8, 9, 6, 4, 7)
df1            = data.frame(category_type = category_type1, category =     category1, weight = weight1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

category_type2 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)
category2      = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 2)
weight2        = c(10, 2, 1, 1, 5 , 7)
df2            = data.frame(category_type = category_type2, category = category2, weight = weight2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:2) {

  assign("data", eval(as.name(dfs[i, "df"])))
  barColours = c(dfs[i, "col1"], dfs[i, "col2"])

  distribution = ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = weight, fill = category_type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = barColours)

  assign(paste0(dfs[i, "df"], "_plot"), distribution)

}

df1_plot
df2_plot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more idiomatic way of doing this in R is to make use of lists:

- create a list of your input data frames
- use `lapply()` to create a new list containing your plots:

Note that this doesn't use `assign()` at all - in general, if you are tempted to use `assign()`, it's an indication that there is almost certainly an easier way of doing this.

Try this:

```
input_data = list(df1, df2)

df_plot <- lapply(1:2, function(i){

  dat <- input_data[[i]]
  barColours = c(dfs[i, "col1"], dfs[i, "col2"])

  ggplot(dat, aes(x = category, y = weight, fill = category_type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = barColours)

})

df_plot[[1]]
df_plot[[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ggplot` objects are only evaluated when printed or built, not when constructed. Since `i` has changed when you print the plot, it will use the new value. One way to deal with this is to explicitly build the plots:

```
plots <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  df = eval(as.name(dfs[i, "df"]))
  barColours = c(dfs[i, "col1"], dfs[i, "col2"])

  distribution = ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = weight, fill = category_type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = barColours)

  plots[[i]] = ggplot_build(distribution)
}
plots[[1]]$plot
```

Note that I have removed your use of `assign`, since I prefer to just store things in lists instead.

My preferred method would be to not use a loop, but a function with lists:

```
f <- function(df, barColours) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = weight, fill = category_type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = barColours)
}

plots <- Map(f, list(df1, df2), list(c('red1', 'red4'), c('green1', 'green4')))
plots[[1]]
```